# How test a React Loadable component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-loadable

I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';

const UploadAsync = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('components/Upload'),
  loading: () => <LoadingComponent full />
});

const Component = () => {
  return <UploadAsync />
}

export default Component
```

And the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from './index';

describe('Component', () => {
  it('should render correctly with upload component', () => {
    const tree = create(<Component />).toJSON();

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

How I can see the Upload component and not the Loading component in the snapshot?

```
exports[`Content should render correctly with form component 1`] = `
  <div>
    <Loading
      full={true}
    />
  </div>
`;
```

So far I have tried `setTimeOut` and `Promises`.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Loadable.preloadAll()` before the tests then you can access the Component you need.

[Docs](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#preloading-ready-loadable-components-on-the-client)

Simple example:

```
all imports here

Loadable.preloadAll()

describe('TestName', () => {
 //tests
})
```

Comment: Loadable.preloadAll() is returning a promise, so this does not seem like it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to figure this out either, but here are a couple of workarounds that, alone or together, may work reasonably well:

**Snapshot test the components that are passed to Loadable**

In your case, the test would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from './components/Upload';

describe('Component', () => {
  it('should render correctly with upload component', () => {
    const tree = create(<Component />).toJSON();

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

You could also test `<LoadingComponent full />` in a similar fashion. No, this doesn't assure you that the `Loadable` component is working, but you *may* find it satisfactory to assume that the `react-loadable` library is well tested and will work as long as you pass to it your own, properly tested components.

**End-to-end browser testing**

Using a framework such as [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [TestCafe](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/) you can write tests that run against your site as it runs in a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `@testing-library/react` and `jest`.
Using the `preloadReady()` function found in the docs here -> https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#preloading-ready-loadable-components-on-the-client

Importantly, I call it after rendering.

```
import { waitFor, render } from "@testing-library/react";

it("should match snapshot with all valid props", async () => {
  const { asFragment } = render(<Component />);

  // wait to load components after rendering
  await waitFor(() => Loadable.preloadReady());

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no proper solution but if your test is actually rendering the component in browser inside iframe then you can get your react component by Jquery contentDocument

```
$('#component-iframe')[0].contentDocument
```

you can find for some specific element in your component by class or id using

```
$('#component-iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById('componentID')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, which I found accidentally, but I don't understand how it works (maybe if we could figure out, we could solve this problem). For now, it's good for a workaround.

If you call mount once outside the test, the dynamic module will load magically:

```js
function mountApp() {
  return mount(
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

mountApp();

// Tests
test('react-loadable module loads', () => {
  const wrapper = mountApp();
  console.log(wrapper.debug());
});
```

Here, the `App`, which contains `react-loadable` modules loads correctly with all its content available. When I remove the first `mountApp`, it doesn't work anymore (it loads only the loading string).

**Edit:**
Actually it works inside the test too, but this way you only need to do this once for every test to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to test a component which had Loadable-components inside of it, and run into a similar problem. I managed to mock those components and that made the parent-component mount (enzyme) as I wanted it to.

I'm leaving out the mocked store and props, as they aren't relevant to the solution

```
const component = () => {
  return mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DoubleMatrix {...props} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

// These are the Loadable-components, import { Grid, GridColumn } from 'App/Components/Tables/Grid' in the parent component which I am testing

jest.mock('App/Components/Tables/Grid', () => ({
  Grid: () => <div />, // eslint-disable-line
  GridColumn: () => <div />, // eslint-disable-line
}))

it('renders', () => {
  const wrapper = component()
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you test the loaded component:

```
import {LoadableFoo} from './loadable-foo';
import {Foo} from './Foo';

it('should load the Foo component', async () => {
  // usual shallow render
  const component = shallow(<LoadableFoo/>);  

  // prerender the Loadable component
  const loadedComponent = await component.preload();

  expect(loadedComponent.Foo).toEqual(Foo);
});
```