# Jest tests fails in react-loadable

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, lazy-loading, enzyme, react-loadable

We have a component that loads with react-loadable, also inside the component we have child components that loads with react-loadable. The problem I face in jest is was not able to load the child components tried few suggestions from internet. Please help on the same, following is requisite details:

lazyload.js

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loader from './components/ui/genericComponents/Loader';
export const lazyload = (func, fallback) => {
    return Loadable({
        loader: func,
        loading: fallback || Loader,
    });
};
```

Component.js

```
import {lazyload} from '../lazyload'
const childComponent1=lazyload(()=>import('./child/childComponent1'));
const childComponent2=lazyload(()=>import('./child/childComponent2'));
const childComponent3=lazyload(()=>import('./child/childComponent3'));
```

Component.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure,mount} from 'enzyme';
import {Component} from '../src/Component';
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

let Wrapper;
beforeAll(() => {
    Wrapper= Enzyme.mount(<Component{...someprops} />);
});

describe('TestSuite for Component',()=>{
//some axios calls
console.log(wrapper.debug()) //I could see the entire wrapper
it('childComponent1',()=>{
console.log(wrapper.debug()) //I only see the loader and not the child Components
})
it('childComponent2',()=>{
console.log(wrapper.debug()) //I only see the loader and not the child Components
})
})
```

Comment: You didn't show what `Component` is.

Comment: Component is just a component that lazyloaded among other components and inside the Component am lazyloading the childcomponents..I have just written like for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the first one here to a similar question to yours:
[How test a React Loadable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176706/how-test-a-react-loadable-component)

This solved the problem for me!

In short, can just do this:

```
// Import your components
    
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
    
Loadable.preloadAll()
    
describe('TestName', () => {
    //tests
});
```